# Force Downloads to appear in Windows 7 Start Menu

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I see the policy to force removal of the Downloads "link" in the Start Menu, but is there a way to force Downloads to be present by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that does this:

http://www.itninja.com/question/win-7-change-folder-view-options-script

You could call that from GP or just modify the registry keys involved directly from GPO

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no policies (or preferences) that support this behavior.  The best way to do this is to create a sysprep'd image with a default profile that has the link set to visible.  This way, any user that logs-in will get this profile.

There may be a way to do a reg hack that forces the link to be visible, but I haven't looked into that...